# Como evitar que el usuario tenga que limpiar el caché o recargar la pagina cuando actualizo componentes de vuejs

Tags: laravel, vue.js, npm

tengo una aplicación con laravel y vuejs, pero cada vez que actualizo los componentes, los pusheo al servidor y corro npm run prod, los usuarios de la aplicación deben recargar la página o incluso algunos borran la caché para que el navegador les muestre el cambio, tanto en pc como smartphone.
Hay algún truco para que esto no lo tengan que hacer,
o como debo buscarlo en google por que no he podido pillarlo, alguna idea? Como siempre, de ante mano gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para evitar que el navegador use el archivo de la cache en vez de cargar el mismo archivo con las modificaciones, agrega el método `version` en el archivo `webpack.mix.js`. Con eso se agregará automáticamente un hash único a los nombres de archivo de todos los archivos compilados y el navegador no lo tomará como si fuese el mismo que tiene en la cache:

```
if (mix.inProduction()) {
    mix.version();
}
```

Después de generar el archivo versionado, no sabrás el nombre exacto del archivo.  Por lo tanto, debes usar la función `mix` de Laravel dentro de tus vistas para cargar el archivo.  La función `mix` determinará automáticamente el nombre actual del archivo hash:

```
<script src="{{ mix('/js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

Referencia Documentación de Laravel:
Compiling Assets (Mix) [Versioning / Cache Busting](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/mix#versioning-and-cache-busting)

Comment: Te pasaste!!! solucionado. por mis bajas votos, no puede dejarlo en 1 tu respuesta :(